# zoom d3.js tree for a particular node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have d3.js tree, when I search on a particular node name I need to make zoom to the particular node. Ideally my tree might contain 1000s of nodes and it will be zoomed out to fit into the screen, when I say focus I want the node to be in center of the page and zoom should be 1:1. Is there a particular d3 event which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an event which does this, instead I made the node focus manually by changing the transition.Hope this will be useful to someone.

```
    /***** get co-ordinates of the entire svg group containing the node. 
           Tree is placed on the centre of the screen 
     ****/
 var svgGroupTranslateCoords =  d3.transform($("#svg").attr("transform"))
     translateX = svgGroupTranslateCoords .translate[0];
     translateY = svgGroupTranslateCoords .translate[1];
     scaleX = svgGroupTranslateCoords .scale[0];
     scaleY = svgGroupTranslateCoords .scale[1];
/******* Get co-ordinates for the node to be highlighted or focused*******/
    var nodeCoords = d3.transform($("#node").attr("transform"))
        ntranslateX = nodeCoords.translate[0];
        ntranslateY = nodeCoords.translate[1];
/**** find the new co-ordinates where the focused node is to be positioned ****/
    var newTranslateX = translateX-ntranslateX;
    var newtranslateY = translateY-ntranslateY
    svgGroup.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + newTranslateX + "," + newtranslateY + ")scale(1,1)");
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the updated code for the lates version of react-d3-tree of zooming to a specific node:

HTML node element:

```
<div class="node" onClick={zoomIn}></div>
```

zoomIn function:

```
const zoomIn = () => {
    const currRef = ref.current;
    const d3 = document.querySelector('.rd3t-tree-container');
    const svgGroupTranslateCoords =  d3.querySelector('.rd3t-svg').querySelector('g');
    const x = svgGroupTranslateCoords.transform.animVal[0].matrix.e;
    const y = svgGroupTranslateCoords.transform.animVal[0].matrix.f;
    const scaleX = svgGroupTranslateCoords.transform.animVal[1].matrix.a;
    const scaleY = svgGroupTranslateCoords.transform.animVal[1].matrix.d;
    const newX = x - currRef.getBoundingClientRect().x + 600 * scaleY ;
    const newY = y - currRef.getBoundingClientRect().y + 300;
    svgGroupTranslateCoords.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${newX}, ${newY}) scale(1, 1)`)
}
```